# Unshare and newuidmap: update

Tags: linux, namespaces

I'm trying to create a process with its own namespace and then make a uid (and possibly gid) mapping. I'm following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972426/891440) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295575/891440), but, as indicated in [this recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972426/unshare-user-namespace-and-set-uid-mapping-with-newuidmap#comment104614123_47295575), it no longer works.

Here's the skinny. First, you create a process in a new namespace with `unshare`:

```
unshare -U bash
```

And obtain the process it runs, with `echo $$` or somesuch. You grab that PID and then, from another shell, you go:

```
newuidmap 12394 0 0 1
```

The answer, as indicated in the comment above, is:

```
newuidmap: uid range [0-1) -> [0-1) not allowed
```

In an update to the answer, [Arks mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972426/unshare-user-namespace-and-set-uid-mapping-with-newuidmap#comment104617924_47295575):

> it is something with settings in /etc/subuid and /etc/subguid files

I can't figure out, however, what they mean. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Still don't understand why newuidmap does not work. But [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/532593/) shows that writing to `/proc/$$/uid_map` does

```
echo '5 1000 1' > /proc/14671/uid_map
```

This is an one-time operation that can't be repeated, and in a single command, establishes the mapping for UIDs and GIDs.